# Prove that, if two distinct cutsets of a graph G each contain an edge e, then G has a cutset that does not contain e.

Tags: graph-theory

I am lost on how to prove this. I am thinking that it has to have something to do with the two distinct cutsets having more than one component to them so using the other components could also create a cutset but I am not sure.

Comment: The cut space of a graph is a vector space with the symmetric difference as addition. Moreover, this vector space is also a matroid. Look up the basic axioms of a matroid and you will see where your exercise comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two cut-sets $(S_1,T_1)$ and $(S_2,T_2)$ in a problem, you can often get a better picture of them by drawing a picture. Put all elements of $T_1\cap T_2$ in "Quadrant I", all elements of $S_1\cap T_2$ in "Quadrant II", all elements in $S_1\cap S_2$ in "Quadrant III", and all elements of $T_1\cap S_2$ in "Quadrant IV":
$$\begin{array}{c|c}\underline{~~S_1\cap T_2~~}&\underline{~~T_1\cap T_2~~}\\S_1\cap S_2&T_1\cap S_2\end{array}$$ Edges in either cut will cross one of the lines (or go through the "origin").

In your case, the edge $e$ goes from Quadrant III to Quadrant I, since it is in both cuts: If $e=uv$, you may assume that $u\in S_1\cap S_2$, and $v\in T_1\cap T_2$.

Note that if $S_1\cap T_2\not=\emptyset$, then $(V(G)\setminus (S_1\cap T_2), S_1\cap T_2)$ is a cut. (Prove this!) It doesn't contain $e$, either. (Prove this!) Similar for $S_2\cap T_1$.

Finally, show that $S_1\cap T_2$ and $S_2\cap T_1$ cannot both be empty.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer:) I found this slightly confusing at first since formally, a cut $(S,T)$ is a partition of the vertices of a graph into two disjoint subsets $S$ and $T$, whereas the *cut-set* determined by $(S,T)$ is the set of edges that have one endpoint in each subset of the partition. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add an illustration to @Christopher's answer :)

[image]
[image]